# PySide GUI freezes during filtering using QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, pyside6

I'm developing a PySide6/Python3 application, that contains a QTableView with a custom model `DataFrameTableModel`. I want to support filtering the rendered table. Hence, I'm using `QSortFilterProxyModel` in addition.

One requirement is to filter based on columns with different operators, e.g. *filter all rows with a value >= 5 in column x*. For representing a filter I implemented the class `DataFrameFilter` which basically just stores something like `{column: 'Price', operator: 'eq', value: 12}`. To apply the custom filter format, I created a class `DataFrameSortFilterProxyModel` that is inheriting from `QSortFilterProxyModel`.

```
from enum import Enum
from PySide6.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, QSortFilterProxyModel, QModelIndex, Qt
import pandas as pd

class DataFrameTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame = None):
        super(DataFrameTableModel, self).__init__()

        self._df: pd.DataFrame = df

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        if parent.isValid() or self._df is None:
            return 0
        
        return self._df.shape[0]
        

    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        if parent.isValid() or self._df is None:
            return 0

        return self._df.shape[1]

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = ...) -> object:
        if index.isValid() and self._df is not None:
            value = self._df.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]

            if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
                return str(value)
            elif role == Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole:
                return value

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int = ...) -> object:
        if self._df is not None:
            if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
                if orientation == Qt.Orientation.Horizontal:
                    return str(self._df.columns[section])
                else:
                    return str(self._df.index[section])
            elif role == Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole:
                if orientation == Qt.Orientation.Horizontal:
                    return self._df.columns[section]
                else:
                    return self._df.index[section]

    def flags(self, index: QModelIndex) -> Qt.ItemFlag:
        return Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled
    
    @property
    def df(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        return self._df
    
    @df.setter
    def df(self, value: pd.DataFrame):
        self._df = value
        self.layoutChanged.emit()

class DataFrameFilterOperation(Enum):
    EQUAL = "eq"
    NOT_EQUAL = "ne"
    GREATER_THAN = "gt"
    GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL = "ge"
    LESS_THAN = "lt"
    LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL = "le"

class DataFrameFilter:
    def __init__(self, column: str, column_index: int, operation: DataFrameFilterOperation, value):
        self._column = column
        self._column_index = column_index
        self._operation = operation
        self._value = value

    @property
    def column(self) -> str:
        return self._column
    
    @property
    def column_index(self) -> int:
        return self._column_index

    @property
    def operation(self) -> DataFrameFilterOperation:
        return self._operation

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value
    
    def __eq__(self, value: object) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(value, DataFrameFilter):
            return False
        
        return self._column == value.column and self._column_index == value.column_index and self._operation == value.operation and self._value == value.value
    
    def __ne__(self, __value: object) -> bool:
        return not self.__eq__(__value)

class DataFrameSortFilterProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    OPERATIONS = {
        DataFrameFilterOperation.EQUAL: lambda x, y: x == y,
        DataFrameFilterOperation.NOT_EQUAL: lambda x, y: x != y,
        DataFrameFilterOperation.GREATER_THAN: lambda x, y: x > y,
        DataFrameFilterOperation.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL: lambda x, y: x >= y,
        DataFrameFilterOperation.LESS_THAN: lambda x, y: x < y,
        DataFrameFilterOperation.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL: lambda x, y: x <= y
    }

    def __init__(self):
        super(DataFrameSortFilterProxyModel, self).__init__()

        self._filters = []

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row: int, source_parent: QModelIndex) -> bool:
        result = []

        for filter in self._filters:
            value = self.sourceModel().index(source_row, filter.column_index, source_parent).data(Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole)
            result.append(self.OPERATIONS[filter.operation](value, filter.value))
        
        return all(result)
    
    def lessThan(self, left: QModelIndex, right: QModelIndex) -> bool:
        left_value = left.data(Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole)
        right_value = right.data(Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole)

        return left_value < right_value
    
    def add_filter(self, filter: DataFrameFilter):
        self._filters.append(filter)
        self.invalidate()

    def remove_filter(self, filter: DataFrameFilter):
        self._filters.remove(filter)
        self.invalidate()
    
    def clear_filters(self):
        self._filters.clear()
        self.invalidate()
```

**Problem:** Basically, everything works wonderfully for small data sets. The problem is that for larger data sets (~60000 rows) filtering obviously takes so long that the GUI freezes for a couple of seconds. I thought about moving the filtering logic to a second thread (`QThread`), but the UI should only be manipulated in the GUI thread, and since editing the model also changes the UI, I cannot adapt the model from a second thread.

It's not a problem if the filtering takes a few seconds, it's just that the UI shouldn't freeze during this time so that you can display a progress bar or something like that. Any suggesstions or solutions?

**EDIT 03/11/24**

I came up with a custom solution by implementing a custom `QTableModel` without using a `QSortFilterProxyModel` at alll. The idea is to outsource filtering to a second `QThread` controlled by a method of the custom model. The model itself isn't altered until filtering is finished. The separate thread will return the finally filtered `DataFrame` and it will be applied to the model instance that has started the thread. This means the UI no longer freezes and loading animations can be displayed and controlled via Qt Signals.

`model.py`:

```
from enum import Enum
from PySide6.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, QModelIndex, Qt, QThreadPool, Signal
import pandas as pd
from thread import DataFrameFilterTask

class DataFrameTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    beginFiltering = Signal()
    endFiltering = Signal()
    beginSorting = Signal()
    endSorting = Signal()
    beginTransforming = Signal()
    endTransforming = Signal()

    def __init__(self, base_df: pd.DataFrame = None):
        super(DataFrameTableModel, self).__init__()

        self._base_df: pd.DataFrame = base_df
        self._transformed_df: pd.DataFrame = None
        self._filters: list[DataFrameFilter] = []
        self._is_filtering = False
        self._is_sorting = False
    
    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        if parent.isValid() or self._current_df is None:
            return 0
        
        return self._current_df.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        if parent.isValid() or self._current_df is None:
            return 0

        return self._current_df.shape[1]

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = ...) -> object:
        if index.isValid() and self._current_df is not None:
            value = self._current_df.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]

            if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
                return str(value)
            elif role == Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole:
                return value

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int = ...) -> object:
        if self._current_df is not None:
            if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
                if orientation == Qt.Orientation.Horizontal:
                    return str(self._current_df.columns[section])
                else:
                    return str(self._current_df.index[section])
            elif role == Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole:
                if orientation == Qt.Orientation.Horizontal:
                    return self._current_df.columns[section]
                else:
                    return self._current_df.index[section]

    def flags(self, index: QModelIndex) -> Qt.ItemFlag:
        return Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled

    @property
    def base_df(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        return self._base_df
    
    @base_df.setter
    def base_df(self, value: pd.DataFrame):
        self._base_df = value
        self._transformed_df = None
        self.layoutChanged.emit()

    @property
    def transformed_df(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        return self._transformed_df
    
    @property
    def filters(self) -> list[DataFrameFilter]:
        return self._filters
    
    @property
    def is_filtering(self) -> bool:
        return self._is_filtering
    
    @property
    def is_sorting(self) -> bool:
        return self._is_sorting
    
    @property
    def is_transforming(self) -> bool:
        return self._is_filtering or self._is_sorting
    
    @property
    def _current_df(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        return self._base_df if self._transformed_df is None else self._transformed_df
    
    def add_filter(self, filter: DataFrameFilter):
        self._filters.append(filter)
        self._apply_filters()

    def remove_filter(self, filter: DataFrameFilter):
        self._filters.remove(filter)
        self._apply_filters()
    
    def clear_filters(self):
        self._filters.clear()
        self._apply_filters()
    
    def _apply_filters(self):
        self.beginFiltering.emit()
        self._is_filtering = True

        task = DataFrameFilterTask(self._base_df.copy(deep=True), self._filters)
        task.signals.data.connect(self._on_filter_task_data)
        task.signals.finished.connect(self._on_filter_task_finished)
        task.signals.error.connect(self._on_filter_task_error)

        QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(task)
    
    def _on_filter_task_data(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._transformed_df = df
        self.endResetModel()
    
    def _on_filter_task_finished(self):
        self._is_filtering = False
        self.endFiltering.emit()
    
    def _on_filter_task_error(self, error: tuple[Exception, type, str]):
        raise error[0]
```

`thread.py`:

```
import sys
import traceback
from PySide6.QtCore import QRunnable, Signal, QObject
import pandas as pd

class DataFrameFilterTaskSignals(QObject):
    finished = Signal()
    error = Signal(Exception)
    data = Signal(pd.DataFrame)

class DataFrameFilterTask(QRunnable):
    OPERATIONS = {
        "eq": lambda x, y: x == y,
        "ne": lambda x, y: x != y,
        "lt": lambda x, y: x < y,
        "le": lambda x, y: x <= y,
        "gt": lambda x, y: x > y,
        "ge": lambda x, y: x >= y
    }

    def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame, filters: list):
        super(DataFrameFilterTask, self).__init__()

        self.signals = DataFrameFilterTaskSignals()
        self._df = df
        self._filters = filters
    
    def run(self):
        try:
            for filter in self._filters:
                if self._df[filter.column].dtype != type(filter.value):
                    self._df = self._df[self._df[filter.column].apply(lambda x: type(x) == type(filter.value))]
                    self._df = self._df[self.OPERATIONS[filter.operation.value](self._df[filter.column], filter.value)]
                else:
                    self._df = self._df[self.OPERATIONS[filter.operation.value](self._df[filter.column], filter.value)]

            self.signals.data.emit(self._df)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((value, exctype, traceback.format_exc()))
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit()
```

Any comments on my solution? It does work without any freezing issues, but I'm not sure if this is common practice or more a quick and dirty solution... Is it better practice to keep `DataFrameTableModel` untouched and create a second `DataFrameSortFilterProxyModel` inheriting from `QAbstractProxyModel` that contains the thread handling logic and updates the `sourceModel()` (a `DataFrameTableModel` instance) from outside of the class by setting the filtered `DataFrame` to fulfill the separation of concerns principle?

Comment: One possibility could be to add a custom signal to the proxy and emit it whenever the filter is invalidated, then connect that signal to a function in the UI that shows a message/dialog (and calls `processEvents()` to ensure it's properly displayed); then hide the progress once filtering has completed with another signal. Unfortunately, showing a progress bar is not effective nor doable: there's no way to know the current progress status, and forcing further `processEvents()` to update an "infinite" progress bar would actually decrease performance even more.

Comment: @musicamante Okay that notifies the user about the process. Is it a good idea to processEvents() outside of the main/exec loop of Qt? This could lead to undefined behaviour if the a second action related to the table data is triggered during filtering, right?

Comment: Just show a modal dialog or prevent any action that would potentially affect the model. You could even add a simple bool flag and override `invalidateFilter()` accordingly: if the flag is set, just ignore the call and return, otherwise set it before `super().invalidateFilter()` is actually called and unset it once it's finished.

Comment: Note that a slight improvement may be achieved if you used specifically targeted functions instead of iterating through all possible operations every time. For instance, supposing an "eq operation", `_operation` may actually just be `lambda x: x == value`. In this way, you don't need to go through all the if/elif, and you can just do `return filter.operation(value)`.

Comment: @musicamante Good idea, I updated my code in `filterAcceptsRow` slightly, but the problem remains. The UI still freezes... I guess I need some kind of threading to solve this...

Comment: I sincerely doubt that using a separate thread would improve anything: you'd be just moving the heavy computation somewhere else, while still blocking the UI in the meantime, unless you introduce a cyclical release (very small `time.sleep()` intervals) which would only partially prevent freezing, and, most importantly, increase the computation time a lot more. And you won't be able to use an actual QSortFilterProxyModel, but you'd need to use a "virtual proxy" that would eventually react to the source signals, which would make things quite more complex.

Comment: For large models, it's best to create the model in a QThread and then simply fill the table from the model again. Quick test now using Polars on about 650k rows by 9 columns, it's nearly instant. I'm using sorting but filtering would be roughly the same.

Answer (score -2):

In Qt, main thread is reserved for GUI only. As you mentioned before for small datasets, freezing doesn't happen, it is because it operates so fast, you can't see the freezing itself but the same thing happens. You only notice once the dataset is huge so it requires more time to calculate it. Your only, and proper, way out is to move calculations to different thread.

What you do actually is you create a Worker class, a class where you will instantiate your class which does the calculations work.
I will imitate your working class and GUI.

Let's say your class that does calculation is DataFrameSortFilterProxyModel and you don't want to touch or change actual inheritance of the class

```
class DataFrameSortFilterProxyModel():
      progress = QtCore.Signal(int)
      finished = QtCore.Signal()
      def filtering(self):
          datasetLength = 1000000000
          for i in range(datasetLength):
              # do the actual work
              emit progress(i/datasetLength)
          emit finished()
```

Now in your worker class you instantiate your class:

```
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = QtCore.Signal()
    progress = QtCore.Signal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        self.mySortingModel = DataFrameSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.mySortingModel.progress.connect(self.updateProgress)
        self.mySortingModel.finished.connect(self.onFinished)
        self.mySortingMode.filtering()

    def updateProgress(self, numProgress):
        emit progress(numProgress)

    def onFinished(self):
        emit finished()
```

Now let's go back to your UI class where you said it should have some kind of progress bar, for simplicity I will use QLabel, but you are free to use QProgressBar or maybe a widget with some GIF animation:

```
    from PySide2.QtCore import QThread
    ...
    ...
    self.progressText = QLabel("0%")
    ...
    def calculate():
        # instantiate different thread
        self.thread = QThread()
        # create a worker
        self.worker = Worker()
        # move worker to the thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        # connect all signals and slots
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.updateProgress)
        
        # start the thread so the actual work is started
        self.thread.start()

        # if you don't want to calculations be bullied by user you can disable action that leads to calculations for example if you have button you would say
        self.calculateBtn.setEnabled(False)
    
        #connect signals what happens in between and after the calcs are over
        self.thread.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.calculateBtn.setEnabled(True)
        )
        self.thread.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.progressText.setText("0%")
        )

def updateProgress(self, progressNum):
    self.progressText.setText(f'{progressNum}%')
```

This should solve your GUI freezing problem, but unfortunately you will need to restructure your calculations class to enable getting info about the progress from it. And don't forget to update your actual graph from self.thread.finished to actually display data.

Comment: This is invalid and also unrunnable. 1. the `DataFrameSortFilterProxyModel` doesn't inherit from QObject, so it will never be able to emit signals; 2. both snippets on top will raise a syntax error because of the `emit ...`; 3. the bottleneck is the filtering, which can only happen in the thread of the model (which in this case has to be the main thread), and is caused by the continuous calls the model has to do to `filterAcceptsRow()`, which, for obvious reasons, could not be moved to another thread; 4. using threading for this is almost always useless, and it often makes things just worse;

Comment: 5. unless there is some way to release control in the worker (such a basic `time.sleep()` at each iteration, this will accomplish absolutely nothing different than doing the same in the main thread, because the worker is CPU bound, preventing the main thread to do anything until the other allows it; 6. maybe you didn't, but I hope you've not been using a generative AI to create this answer, as such contents are [currently banned on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) due to unreliability of the results and their generated code, which often contains typos (like `emit ...`).

Comment: 1. I did not generate it through AI

Comment: 2. I don’t know but maybe he can inherit from mentioned class and QObject then will be able to emit the signals. Or just manually do the filtering. I just said core QT principle that main thread is reserved for GUI and heavy operations must be moved to anorher thread. Sorry for syntax errors but I am primarily C++ developer, and written answer in stackoverflow web IDE along the code. I also had a bad day at work so a little help can do no harm. Thanks for pointing out syntax errors, I hope the person get the idea of programming in QT.

Comment: While moving CPU bound tasks *may* sometimes work in C++, this is almost always invalid in Python (due to the GIL) unless the threaded functions periodically return control in some way (eg. using `time.sleep()` every every now and again), with the result that moving such a computation to a thread would still freeze the UI or, at least, slow down the process by a fair amount. Yes, it's possible to create a proxy model that doesn't completely freeze the UI and does filtering in a separate thread, either by using a "fake proxy" (similarly to QConcatenateTablesProxyModel) or even a »

Comment: » QAbstractProxyModel subclass, but implementing such a mechanism in a reliable and effective way is not an easy task at all, especially if, for some reason, we should also consider possible changes to the source model that may actually happen in the meantime (which is exactly what a separate thread would allow). For such a situation, calling `processEvents()` (with a few safe measures) is certainly a simpler and more effective solution. That said, I'm sorry for your bad day, I wish you some better ones.